# Spectral radius of a time-varying matrix with strictly positive increment of the matrix's entry

Tags: graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory, eigenvalues

Consider a time varying non-negative matrix $A(t)$ and its spectral radius $\rho(A(t))$ being the largest eigenvalue of $A(t)$ and $t$ denotes the time. If $A(t)$ changes over time with each time a random element in $A(t)$ is being increased by a random value, will the spectral radius be monotonously increasing over time as well?

In other words, can I say that:

$\rho(A(1))\leq\rho(A(2))\ldots\leq\rho(A(N))$

If yes, how do I proof this?

If no, why?

Comment: Is your matrix symmetric? (If so, how do you keep it symmetric?) Does "positive" mean positive spectrum or positive entries?

Comment: No, the matrix is not necessarily symmetric. By "positive" I mean positive entries of the matrix $A$. I just edited the title to reflect this.

Comment: Your question can be rephrased as: if $A$ and $B$ are non-negative matrices where $A_{ij}\le B_{ij}$ for each $i$ and $j$, then is it the case that $\rho(A)\le \rho(B)$? The answer is yes.

Comment: And if $A$ is primitive,then the inequality is strict.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anthony and David are referring to the Perron-Frobenius Theorem, which easily proves the monotonicity you ask about. There is a precise quantitative result in my paper *Perturbations of Shifts of Finite Type*, SIAM J. Disc. Math. 2 (1989), 350-365:

Lemma 6: Let $A = [a_{i,j}]$ be a real square matrix with simple eigenvalue $\rho(A)$ and corresponding (row) left eigenvector $v>0$ and (column) right eigenvector $w>0$. Then the matrix of partial derivatives of $\rho(A)$ with respect to the entries of $A$ is given by
$$
  \left[\frac{\partial \rho(A)}{\partial a_{ij}}\right]=\frac{wv}{vw}.
$$

The proof is a simple application of the chain rule applied to $Aw=\lambda w$, where $\lambda=\rho(A)$, and is actually true for every simple (i.e. multiplicity one) eigenvalue of $A$.